# nonfatal error in SSIS package from deleted Script Task

Tags: ssis, bids

I am working in BIDS for 2008 R2

I have an annoying issue that I have not found the solution to yet. The error message is below. The line of code the error message refers to was from a Script Task that I deleted yesterday. My SSIS package executes fine and I am getting close to publishing the production version. I would like to clean up this non-fatal error first.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to clear this up?

Thanks!

*Attempt to parse the expression "@[User::SS_Directory] +"''" + @["User::SS_InputFolderName] + "\" + @[User:SS_InputFileName]" failed and returned error code 0xC00470A6. The expression cannot be parsed. It might contain invalid elements or it might no be well-formed. There may also be an out-of-memory error.*

Comment: You deleted a Script Task which contained the failing expression yet SSIS still reports that the expression exists?

Comment: Yup. I only have two script tasks currently in the package and I triple checked them just to be certain. I deleted the other script task by right clicking on it in the Control Flow and then hitting the delete key. My guess is that left the C# SciptMain somewhere.

Comment: You may need to do a find within the xml code to determine where that expression is.

Comment: With all due respect, I'd look elsewhere. That syntax error is for an SSIS Expression. Everything in the SSIS world can have expressions so Variables, Containers, etc are all suspect. The problem with the supplied expression is that you needed to escape the \ making it `+"\\"+`

Comment: @billinkc That particular line I know I wrote in the Script task. After a rebuild, is there a particular SSIS object that would have persisted code outside of the script task?

Comment: Have you tried opening the package as 'view code' and searching for the expression?

Comment: @Jayvee Yes. I've worked through most of the suggestions here without resolution.

Comment: @billinkc My naivete shows through. It was indeed elsewhere. There was a variable that had also used the same syntax as the script task. I just stumbled upon it today.

Answer (score 0):

try

- to rename the pkg and rebuild it, then rename back again.
- check the connection manager
- use format -> auto layout- diagram
- open as text and lok for the string in the error
  Mario